# Can we enable tracking a badge statistic even if you already have the badge?

Tags: feature-request, badge-progress

There is a page in the user profile where you can choose which badge to track next. This page shows your current progress towards the badge:

[image: Screenshot of badge tracking page for available badges]

I am often interested in seeing my statistics even when I already have the relevant badge. For example, I already have the Sportsmanship badge, but I would still like to be able to easily see how many times I have upvoted other answers to questions where I have posted an answer. There is another tab that includes all badges (even ones that were already earned), but it doesn't give you the statistics anymore. It just tells you that you have the badge:

[image: Screenshot of badge tracking page for all badges]

Can this tool be edited to continue to track your "progress" even *after* you have the badge. In other words, instead of just telling me that I have the Sportsmanship badge, it would tell me that my progress is 117/100 (or some other way of supplying me with the data).

I imagine that this information can be gleaned using SEDE, but that is a bother, it doesn't contain the most recent data, and would probably need a separate query for each category.

If there is another way to obtain this data feel free to point it out.

Comment: Same here. Want to track another socratic, but can't )=

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a great idea for the badges that can be earned multiple times, namely the Socratic badge.

I know that I am close to earning a second Socratic badge on the Great Outdoors, but if I want to know exactly how close, well I have to go track down the right SEDE query and enter my user id. Being able to see it from my dashboard would be a great improvement.